# Meteor AutoForm - Invalid Field Name with Array Index

Tags: meteor

I've got this in my Simple Schema:

```
  "servicesSelected.0.sku" : {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
```

Basically, I want the `sku` key in the first array item of `servicesSelected` to be a String and optional.

Here's my form code, which is for a checkbox.

```
  {{> afFieldInput class="track-order-change" type="checkbox" checkbox="true" template="" name="servicesSelected.0.sku" value="hdrPhotos"}}
```

The error I get is Invalid Field Name "servicesSelected.0.sku"

As soon as I remove the array index in both the schema and the afFieldInput the error goes away, but the point is to validate the data that is in array index 0...

I am going to assume that it's invalid because in JS you can't have a number as the first character in a key name if you are using dot notation.

But Simple Schema and Autoform do not support square bracket notation...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if SimpleSchema allows you to validate an array like this. A custom validation might be necessary.

I understand that the idea here is that the first element of the array can have the `sku` property, but others cannot. In this case, try the following method:

```
servicesSelected: {
  type: [selectedServiceSchema],
  custom: function() {
    for(var i=1; i<this.value.length; ++i) {
      if(this.value[i].sku) return "SKU set in the wrong service";
    }
  },
},
```